# Regarding matrix representation of $SO(4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, quantum-mechanics

As per the title of the question, what are the matrix elements of the special orthogonal group $SO(4)$? I'm not certain but I believe they are somehow related to being operators of angular momentum denoted by $\hat{L}_i,  \hat{L}_j, \hat{L}_k, \hat{L}_m$.

Comment: The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ of $SO(4)$ is the vector space of all skew-symmetric real $4 \times 4$ matrices. A conventional basis for this $6$-dimensional space is given by $\{L_{ij}\}_{1 \leq i < j \leq 4}$, where $$L_{ij} := E_{ij} - E_{ji}$$ for $E_{ij}$ the matrix whose only non-zero entry is $(E_{ij})_{ij} = 1$. Geometrically, the basis vector $L_{ij}$ can be interpreted as the infinitesimal generator of rotations on the $x_i x_j$-plane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$SO(4)$ is the group of rotations about the origin in $4$-dimensional space. [See this.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space)

Comment: That I'm aware of. I was wondering what the specific rotation matrices would be (consisting of $0,\pm{1}$) to represent $SO(4)$ just as there are specific rotation matrices that represent $SO(3)$. What is clear is that such matrices ought to have determinant $1$, I think.

Comment: It the definition that they have determinant 1. That's what the S stands for. To be a little more specific, they are exactly the matrices that preserve the dot product and have determinant 1. $u\cdot v=(Au)\cdot (Av)$.

Comment: Actually, I would like to know what would be the generators of $SO(4)$ in matrix form. In the following link, at the bottom of p. 101, the generators of $SO(3)$ are given.
http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS480/qm_PDF/chp5.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean by generators. In that article, the statement that those are generators of $SO(3)$ is false by a mathematical definition of generators.

Comment: So what do you think they meant by saying that? Would we just consider them as matrix representations of $SO(4)$?

Comment: I think what they are calling generators are actually a basis for the Lie algebra. That makes sense.

Comment: Those aren't generators in the naive sense, but they are "infinitesimal generators," i.e., they're a basis for the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$ of $SO(3)$. It's traditional in the physics literature to systematically conflate Lie groups with their Lie algebras.

Comment: They sort of do generate the group via the exponential map, so I'm not horribly offended.